# Cannot listen to Bootstrap events when compiling with webpack

Tags: webpack, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a listener for when a dropdown closes, but the event seemingly never fires.

Javascript:

```js
$('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
  //do something
);
```

I have even added the listener to the document but the event never fires. I am importing all of bootstrap via npm. No other events seem to fire either. I'm not sure if possibly the compiler is messing things up because when i load Bootstrap in from a CDN the event works just fine.

Here is the only test I am using for JS:

```
{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with not being able to listen to Tab events and Collapse only able to expand. The problem was with my webpack.config.js HtmlWebpackPlugin configuration.

I have a multi-page app, so I have multiple HtmlWebpackPlugins for each page, and for each page, I wanted to include a script to populate the header and select the current page. I did that by using the `chunks` property, but because I have to include Bootstrap for the it, I think it was somehow double-loading Bootstrap. I removed it from `chunks` and instead imported it for each script, and everything was working again.